# Is there any way to roll up groupings in different columns in tSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've got a few columns that have different amounts of the same values:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

For which I'd like to count the totals of each value and return an output like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | B | C |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

From what I can tell the pivot operation will only allow you to count the number of responses in a single column.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select colv, 
       sum(case when colname = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as [A],
       sum(case when colname = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as [B],
       sum(case when colname = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as [C]
from table t cross apply
    ( values ('A', A), ('B', B), ('C', C) 
    ) tt (colname, colv)
group by colv;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `UNPIVOT`, `COUNT`, `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [A] INT
   ,[B] INT
   ,[C] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([A], [B], [C])
VALUES (1, 4, 4)
      ,(2, 4, 3)
      ,(2, 4, 3)
      ,(4, 4, 3)
      ,(3, 2, 3)
      ,(3, 1, 2)
      ,(3, 3, 2)
      ,(1, 1, 1);

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [column]
          ,[value]
          ,COUNT(*) AS [count]
    FROM @DataSource
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [value] FOR [column] IN ([A], [B], [C])
    ) UNPVT
    GROUP BY [column]
            ,[value]
) DS
PIVOT
(
  MAX([count]) FOR [column] IN ([A], [B], [C])
) PVT;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns is limited and possible values are limitid as well, you could use multiple CTE's and UNION (ALL) the results:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS Col, COUNT(*) AS A,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS B FROM T AS T2 WHERE B = 1 ) AS B,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM T AS T3 WHERE C = 1 ) AS C
    FROM T
    WHERE A = 1
)
, CTE_2 AS 

(
    SELECT 2 AS Col, COUNT(*) AS A,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS B FROM T AS T2 WHERE B = 2 ) AS B,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM T AS T3 WHERE C = 2 ) AS C
    FROM T
    WHERE A = 2
)
, CTE_3 AS 

(
    SELECT 3 AS Col, COUNT(*) AS A,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS B FROM T AS T2 WHERE B = 3 ) AS B,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM T AS T3 WHERE C = 3 ) AS C
    FROM T
    WHERE A = 3
)
 , CTE_4 AS 

(
    SELECT 4 AS Col, COUNT(*) AS A,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS B FROM T AS T2 WHERE B = 4 ) AS B,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM T AS T3 WHERE C = 4 ) AS C
    FROM T
    WHERE A = 4
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE_2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE_3 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE_4
```